# How to automatically link commit-history to a ticketing system?

Tags: gitlab, jira, gitlab-auto-devops

Our organization uses Gitlab to host all our git-repositories. Most commits refer to one (sometimes more) Jira-tickets and/or other issue-trackers. Something like:

```
Add a widget to the trinket

Jira: FOOBAR-1117
ServiceNow: INC0000001319
```

or even simply:

```
FOOBAR-1119: add a bell to the wistle
```

The commit-messages themselves are, obviously, in plain text -- and that's, how it should be. However, when viewing individual commits (or the whole history) *with a browser*, one would like the ticket-references to be *clickable* -- each one leading directly to the referenced ticket.

Can Gitlab be configured to do such a thing automatically?

Atlassian Jira, for example, can be configured to link tickets to commits in Git, Subversion and other revision-control systems: when viewing FOOBAR-1119, I can see all commits referencing it.

Can Gitlab be likewise configured to link to the issue-tracker(s), when rendering a commit-message in HTML?